# Xamarin Forms Editor control, HeightRequest problem

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an editor control which works fine if setup like so:

```
this.MinimumHeightRequest = 50;
this.AutoSize = EditorAutoSizeOption.TextChanges;
this.Text = this.ThisGMPControl.Value;
```

However, if I put a `HeightRequest` in, like so...

```
this.MinimumHeightRequest = 50;
this.HeightRequest = 100;
this.AutoSize = EditorAutoSizeOption.TextChanges;
this.Text = this.ThisGMPControl.Value;
```

... the editor successfully sets to the requested height, but the text isn't there. When I click on the box to bring into focus, the text then appears.

I've seen some info suggesting I use `ForceLayout()` to make the text appear straight away, but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

I really don't know what to look for here. The only difference is in the `HeightRequest` part.

Comment: Due to i do not have the Value of  ThisGMPControl, I test on xaml and c# code with simple text. Both of them show the text well. I could not reproduce the error. Could you provide the code sample for us?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT `ThisGMPControl.Value` is a string object. The surrounding code is a huge mess right now as it's a conversion from iOS Obj-C to C# code... it looks like a warzone. I suspect the error may well be in there, but I was hoping someone might know immediately why a simple addition of `HeightRequest` would cause this issue.

Comment: Normally, the string object would not make that. Could you check the value? Does this get the correct string object before you output in the Text peoperty?